# The space C(X) and uniformly convergence on compact subsets of X

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a completely regular space. For every compact subset $K$ of X, define a seminorm $p_K: C(X)\to {\Bbb C}$ such that $p_K(f):=\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)|$. Then $\{p_K;K ~is ~compact \}$ is a collection of seminorms that makes $C(X)$ a locally convex space. 
Show that a net $\{f_i\}$ in $C(X)$ converges to $f$ iff $f_i\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $X$.

My attempt; first I let $\{f_i\}$ in $C(X)$ converges to $f$ then for every compact subset  $K$ . $p_k(f-f_i) = \sup_{x\in K}|f(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)| = p_X(f-f_i)$ which show that $f_i\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $X$.

for connverse direction I stuck. Please hint me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f_i$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $K$ if and only if $p_K(f-f_i) \to 0$.

Comment: Dear Daniel, I know about it. my problem is showing that $f_i\to f$ in $C(X)$ where $f_i\to f$ uniformly on every compact subsets.